# Proper GL Driver configuration on RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, opengles

Can someone confirm what I should do on a raspberry pi 4 to access the new DRM based opengl drivers?  I expected to see a new option in raspi-config for it, but instead I only see the legacy and fake KMS options.  I would have assumed these would do nothing, but they do seem to affect the existence of the /dev/dri directory somehow...